# Subtotal cells in wpf datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, wpfdatagrid

I'm attempting to subtotal several rows dynamically when `CellEditEnding` if fired.  Right now, I'm looping through the entire collection to get a total and placing it in the total cell.  See code below:

```
private void CalculateTotals()
    {
        foreach (var i in reviewItems) // total pay is calculated on data load
        {
            if (i.Total_Pay == null || i.IsApproved != true) //total pay is recalculated on save
            {
                i.Total_Pay = GetValue(i.Total_Bonus_Items) + GetValue(i.Total_Hourly_Pay) + 
                    GetValue(i.Total_Line_Items) + GetValue(i.Total_Sick) + 
                    GetValue(i.Total_Adjustments) + GetValue(i.Total_Vacation);
                SavedSummary = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML follows

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="SummaryGrid" Margin="10,66,10,0" CellEditEnding="SummaryGrid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee" Binding="{Binding Emp_Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Period End" Binding="{Binding Week_End_Date, StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Load Pay" Binding="{Binding Total_Line_Items}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference LoadVisibility}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Extra Items" Binding="{Binding Total_Bonus_Items}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference LoadVisibility}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hours" Binding="{Binding Total_Hourly_Pay}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference HourlyVisibility}, Path=Visibility}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vacation" Binding="{Binding Total_Vacation}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference HourlyVisibility}, Path=Visibility}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sick" Binding="{Binding Total_Sick}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference HourlyVisibility}, Path=Visibility}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adjustments" Binding="{Binding Total_Adjustments}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference HourlyVisibility}, Path=Visibility}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Pay" Binding="{Binding Total_Pay}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    Approved
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsApproved, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I've got a Checkbox in MainWindow that I tag to the Primary Key eg `Tag="{Binding tkey}"`that I grab with the data, but I cannot figure out how to grab that from `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` or from `sender` from the event.  Is there a way to capture which row I'm coming from using the tag?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood. You need to update `Total` right after you've edited values in any other valuable cell, right? `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` stores number of row which you edited. Using this you can calculate and update Total value only for current row.
I've created a simple example below. It sums up values in properties val1-val3 and places the sum in a property called "total".

This is a simple class for keeping the properties according to a datasource structure. Note that you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to keep UI updated.

```
public class DataItem:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DataItem(int v1,int v2,int v3)
    {
        val1 = v1;
        val2 = v2;
        val3 = v3;
        total = v1 + v2 + v3;
    }

    private int _val1;
    public int val1
    {
        get { return _val1; }
        set { _val1 = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("val1"));}
    }

    private int _val2;
    public int val2
    {
        get { return _val2; }
        set { _val2 = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("val2")); }
    }

    private int _val3;
    public int val3
    {
        get { return _val3; }
        set { _val3 = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("val3")); }
    }

    private int _total;
    public int total
    {
        get { return _total; }
        set { _total = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("total")); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

This is a code-behind for a MainWindow where DataGrid is placed, here the data are filled and loaded into grid and also the `datagrid_CellEditEnding` event is handled.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        DataItem i1 = new DataItem(3,6,8);
        DataItem i2 = new DataItem(1, 2, 6);
        DataItem i3 = new DataItem(9, 7, 22);
        list.Add(i1);
        list.Add(i2);
        list.Add(i3);
        datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> list;

    private void datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.Row.GetIndex();
        list[index].total = list[index].val1 + list[index].val2 + list[index].val3;
    }
```

And finally, XAML for a `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="datagrid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Val1" Binding="{Binding  Path=val1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Val2" Binding="{Binding  Path=val2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Val3" Binding="{Binding  Path=val3, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="total" FontWeight="Black" Binding="{Binding  Path=total}"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```